# How to force a field to be mandatory?

Tags: templates, user, custom-templates

I want to make it so that all new contacts *must have* a contact type. I have found where the contact type is in the templates, and have managed to add the wee * besides it, but I am struggling to find what tag or code I need to add to make it be an actual mandatory field. Is there some way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SE, You can set contact type mandatory by using [hook_civicrm_buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) something like below

```
function extension_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ('CRM_Contact_Form_Contact' == $formName
    && !($form->getVar('_action') & CRM_Core_Action::DELETE)
  ) {
    $form->addRule('contact_sub_type',  ts('This field is required.'), 'required');
  }
}
```

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: <?php
function civicrm_hooks_civicrm_buildForm($formName, &$form) {
  if ($formName == 'CRM_Contact_Form_Edit_Individual') {
      $form->addRule('contact_sub_type', ts('This field is required.'), 'required');
  }
}  

is what i have so far but I cant get it to work :( any ideas?

Comment: I have managed to set up the hook in drupal etc, and I did see my hook on the page (i forgot the <?php initially)

Comment: Is it working or not?

Comment: Its not working - I have successfully set the hooks up but the hook I have written does not work.

Comment: What is the module or extension name where you have added above code?

Comment: It's in a custom module called civicrm_hooks that has been enabled.

Comment: It should be CRM_Contact_Form_Contact not CRM_Contact_Form_Edit_Individual